# Compare mean heart rate after drug administration with multiple time points against baseline

Tags: anova, spss, paired-data

I want to compare mean heart rate change from baseline (T0) within the group. There are 10 continuous time points (T0,T1,....T10.) like t1 vs t0, t2 vs t0, t3 vs t0.. what test should i apply ? paired t test is appropriate? The studied drug was given at t2.

Comment: Do you have a control group who received a non-drug control? If so then you should think about comparing the drug with the non-drug control rather than just comparing times. (If you don't have a control group then your study may be incomplete in a way that statistics cannot help with.)

Comment: I have 2 drug groups,,  I want to compare baseline heart rate with other time point within the same group and need a p value!      Should I use paired t test or repeated anovo with bonferroni posthoc  to analyse?

Comment: What scientific inference do you wish to make? If you want to know whether both drugs had an effect then you need a control group to compare them with. If you only want to know if one of them had a larger absolute effect than the other than you can compare the two without a control group. The best way to evaluate drugs is by way of dose-response curves. Any single dose study has the possibility that the absence of effect is inadequate dose and any difference between the drugs is simply a difference in their potencies. Statistics cannot make up for bad design.

Comment: Unless your desired inference concerns the time at which the response occurred (or peaked) then do not compare all the time points. Instead, define a time point to be the response time (either the peak of the response variable or a reasonable set time point) and use that as the datum for each patient.

Comment: i compared both groups with unpaired tests..  i am planning to compare intra group variations from baseline... i have got the answer to for repeated measures anova with post hoc

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you do not have a control group (otherwise, you could proceed as similarly but add a group variable to the fit). This makes this kind of tricky, but here's an idea:

Denote with $h_{p,t}$ the heart rate of patient $p \in \mathcal{P}$ at time $t \in \{1, ..., 10\}$, and with $a_{t}$ an indicator variable that takes value one after treatment (i.e. for $t \ge 2$) and zero otherwise. Let the patient mean $m_p \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, follow a normal distribution with mean zero and unknown standard deviation $\sigma$. Finally let $\beta$ and $\mu$ be two fitted parameters.
Now fit the following mixed model:

$$
h_{p, t} = \mu + \beta a_t + m_p
$$

You can now test whether the drug had an effect by testing against the null hypothesis $\beta = 0$.

Intuitively, what this does is it assumes that the heart rate is distributed normally between patients with an unknown mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Furthermore, after the drug has been administered, the heart rate is modulated by a constant $\beta$. However, it does not discriminate between any time-points after administration. I am not sure how one could a time dependency and also test for a drug effect without control group.

The above model can be implemented using the `lme4` package in R, where $m_p$ is a random effect. If you absolutely need p-values, you can use `lmerTest`.